# Sharepoint Calender

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

We have a number of sharepoint calendars for our personnel which can be accessed through sharepoint on office 365. What we would like to do is add these calendars to individuals outlook 365 accounts.

Can this be done?

I have tried the right click other calendars and add calendar. this then asks for a directory but i do not know what directory the sharepoint calendar resides.

Help please

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint calendars do not have a perfect integration into Office 365 calendars. If you are using Microsoft Outlook as client for your Office 365 communication you can follow these steps:

- open the SharePoint Online site providing the calendar
- click into the calendar to make sure the "CALENDAR" ribbon on the top appears
- open this ribbon
- select "connect to Outlook" (see screenshot below)
- in Outlook you can use this calendar as overlay on your personal calendar

[image]

**If this helps please give feedback.**